# Как добавить шрифт на страницу?

Tags: шрифты, html, css

Я нашёл очень красивый шрифт и хочу, чтобы у меня весь текст на `web`-странице был этим шрифтом. Я слышал, что шрифт можно залить на  `FTP`, и как-то подключить к сайту и весь текст будет на этом шрифте. Однако, я не могу найти информацию о том как это сделать: [Вот запрос по которому я пытался найти инфу](http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82+%D0%B2+html&lr=959).

Answer (score 8):

Для кроссбраузерности, надо создать несколько разных форматов выбранного вами шрифта (ttf, eot, svg и т.д.) Это можно сделать [на этом бесплатном сервисе](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) или [этом сервисе](http://www.font2web.com/), если проблемы с кирилическими шрифтами. Загружаете шрифт (напр., **ttf**), получаете на выходе набор необходимых файлов. Подключается, как правильно подсказали коллеги выше, надо используя **@font-face**. Для начала, инициализируем шрифт:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('my-font.eot');
    src: url('my-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('my-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('my-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('tmy-font.svg#MyFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

А дальше, определяем стиль для определенного элемента в обычном режиме:

```
h1 {
    font-family: MyFont;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Может вот так? Нужно добавить в Ваш **CSS**:

```
@font-face { font-family:Название шрифта; src:/fonts/название шрифта.ttf;}
```

А потом, что бы применить ко всему:

```
*{
 font-family:Название шрифта;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как я добавлял `BuxtonSketch`:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'BuxtonSketch';
    src: url('fonts/buxtonsketch.eot');
    src: url('fonts/buxtonsketch.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/buxtonsketch.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/buxtonsketch.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/buxtonsketch.svg#buxtonsketch') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

А в папке `fonts` естественно были файлы `buxtonsketch.eot`, `buxtonsketch.ttf` и `buxtonsketch.woff`.

Answer (score 0):

[Нестандартные шрифты](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [тут](http://www.google.com/webfonts/). Ответа там нету, но добавить оттуда шрифт очень легко.